# Invalid default value for 'createdAt' DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am running the following query in mariadb/ mysql engine.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`Quotes`(`id`INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment ,`quote`TEXT,`author`VARCHAR(255),`genre`VARCHAR(255),`tag`TEXT,`createdAt`DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),`updatedAt`DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(), PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

However, I am getting the following error:

An error occurred while creating the table:

> {Invalid default value for 'createdAt'}

Here is the result of sql mode:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

> STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version are you running.  Allowing a `DEFAULT` on `DATETIME` is a rarely new feature.  (Very old for `TIMESTAMP`.)

Comment: @RickJames thank you so much it was indeed due to old mariadb. I was running 5.x. Now I have upgraded to 10.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datetime/ :

> MariaDB starting with 10.0.1 Since MariaDB 10.0.1, DATETIME columns
>   also accept CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value.

Note that `NOW()` is not mentioned, but the effect is the same.